# codeigniter routes similar parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm trying to create a `function album_create()` that handles both insert and update process according to the parameters sent. this function needs routing to make the url prettier, so this is my routes.php:

```
$route['community/(\w.+)/album/create/(\w.+)'] = 'community/album_create/$1/$2';
$route['community/(\w.+)/album/create'] = 'community/album_create/$1';
$route['community/(\w.+)/album'] = 'community/album/$1';
```

and this is the php controller methods :

```
function album() {
  // some code here
}

function album_create($parent_id, $post_id='') {
  // some code here
}
```

unfortunately, only the second and third line of routing works, but the first line doesn't.

```
/community/12/album/create/9 // this url doesn't work
/community/12/album/create // this url works
/community/12/album // this url works
```

by doesn't work, I mean it only shows `404 Page Not Found`

does anyone have an idea where the problem is??